# Protobuf: How to use the --encode command on console

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc

When I use the `--encode` command by the `protoc` compiler I can type in my input via the standard input (`key:value`), but it stays in the input mode. I never get any result. How do I get it?

Comment: The content of the question does not match the title; the title should specify the part about being stuck in input mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to press `Ctrl + D` to send a End-of-Transmission character.